# Unable to parse a certain value from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in python in combination with selenium to scrape "Latitude" from a website which is in this case "49°57'09"N (49.952500)" but for some reason I'm getting TimeoutException instead. I can't understand where I'm getting derailed from. Any input on this will be vastly appreciated.

The script I'm trying with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.gcmap.com/airport/EDEF")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.switch_to_frame(0)
for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[contains(@class,'vcard')]//td/abbr[@class='latitude']"))):
    print(item.text)  
driver.quit()
```

Elements in which the latitude resides:

```
<td colspan="2" nowrap=""><abbr class="latitude" title="49.952500"></abbr>49°57'09"N (49.952500)</td>
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that the text desired is not inside the `<abbr>` tag, it's inside it's parent, the `<td>` tag. To find the element's parent, you can use the XPath's *double-dot* syntax with `.find_element_by_xpath("..")`. Also, finding the `<abbr>` by it's class name is a much cleaner way than to use it's XPath. Note no waiting(neither explicit or implicit) was necessary for the code below to work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.gcmap.com/airport/EDEF")

item = driver.find_element_by_class_name('latitude')
itemParentText = item.find_element_by_xpath("..").text
```

---

```
>>> print(itemParentText)
49°57'09"N (49.952500)
```

Comment: Thanks Vinícius Aguiar, for your sharp and effective solution. A oneliner explanation or any link as to why (..) syntax should be applied would be much appreciated. Forgive my ignorance and thanks once again.

Comment: I'm glad to help! I don't think `selenium` has something similar to bs4's `.findParent` so that is definetely a *workaround*, although it seems the best way to do this, you can check this XPath's syntax "explanation" in [this w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp).